# Syntactic Errors in project files only in my system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am getting syntactic errors in ruby files in my system although these are not there in other systems.

**The errors are in code like:**

1) `redirect_to :back, alert: exception.message`

The syntactic error is in `alert`

2) `load_and_authorize_resource only: [ :update, :destroy ]`

The syntactic error is in `only`

3) `render json: @reward.to_json`

The syntactic error is in `json`

Like that there are number of errors.

**I am getting rid of these errors by doing following changes to the above:**

1) `redirect_to :back, :alert => exception.message`

2) `load_and_authorize_resource :only => [ :update, :destroy ]`

3) `render :json => @reward.to_json`

It seems that error is due to ruby version but I am not sure what's the proper reason is?

I need to do all such changes in every existing projects and is quite painful.

Does that imply that the projects are using old ruby syntax or does that imply that I have old ruby version installed?

My ruby version is `ruby 1.9.2p180`

Also if its ruby version problem than does the ruby upgrade to the latest version will affect the whole project and how to accomplish this easily ?

UPDATE:

I confirmed that my ruby version is `ruby 1.9.2p180` because of the following:

```
D:\ruby_work>ruby -v
  ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]


D:\ruby_work>pik list
  187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i386-mingw32]
* 192: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

The asteric(*) above is indicating the version I am currently using.

The exact errors are for example in  `redirect_to :back, :alert => exception.message` is-

```
, unexpected ':'
```

UPDATE:

Now I did -

```
D:\ruby_work>pik use 187

D:\ruby_work>pik list
* 187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i386-mingw32]
  192: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

D:\ruby_work>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i386-mingw32]
```

The error is still there. Now I suspect Is it really a ruby error because changing to older ruby version also showing the same syntactic error. The only difference is that now even changing from `:key` to `key =>` is also showing the same error.

Comment: Please show the *exact* error you are receiving. Saying "syntactic errors" doesn't tell us enough.

Comment: While you set your Ruby version using pic, it's entirely possible that the code isn't being run by that version. `#!` lines can cause a hard-coded version to run, different than what your environment says. Adding `puts RUBY_VERSION` will tell what the real version is that is running at that moment. Also, you don't show how you are starting the application, which can also control which version of Ruby is used. As is, this smells like Ruby 1.8.7 running, not any sort of Ruby bug. Odds are really good you haven't found any sort of bug but it's user error.

Comment: The error was because you're using Ruby 1.9 hash syntax in Ruby 1.8. Without more context the new error makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Ruby didn't understand the hash notation of `key: value`, only `:key => value`, which 1.9+ understands.

I don't remember when the new notation was added, but, as you found, the fix to allow the code to run on older versions is to use the original notation.

---

In Ruby 1.8.7, this is the error I get using IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = {a:'b'}
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
foo = {a:'b'}
          ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
    from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> foo = {:a => 'b'}
=> {:a=>"b"}
```

Comment: So as my ruby version is 1.9+, so do I need to manually change each ruby file from `key: value` to `:key => value` ?

Comment: Are you running RVM or rbenv, and have multiple versions of Ruby installed? If so, confirm carefully that you are really running the version you think. The error won't happen with 1.9+, but 1.8+ will definitely do it.

Comment: I am on windows so here I am using `pik` because `rvm` is not for windows as far as I know. I have two ruby versions installed: `ruby 1.8.7` and `ruby 1.9.2p180`. For this project, I am using latest ruby version.

Comment: I suspect you are really running Ruby 1.8.7 when encountering the errors. Try adding `puts RUBY_VERSION` to your code just above the point the error occurs, and see what it says.

Comment: Please see my updated question and I am sure that I am using latest version of ruby. The problem is the project is old one and I doubt that it is having older ruby syntax as I mentioned. One solution is that I have to switch back to older ruby version to get rid of all these errors but I want to use latest ruby version. So do I need to change every line which contains error from key: value to :key => value ?